# JSON API problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova

i would like to know why the json is wrapped between (); in this json api which i want to work with but i cant manage to find the way to, thank you all.

This is one example of the api: http://www.etnassoft.com/api/v1/get/?id=589

And the page of the api: https://openlibra.com/es/page/public-api

PS: I'm working with javascript in apache cordova project.

Edit: Im pretty new working with APIS so im sorry if someone is upset about the question.

Comment: Where do you see the ( // ); ?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/c3c5d47a8f13391882f1b0ef5b82d137  At the beggining an at the end of every api link.

Comment: its api what it has to do with JS ??

Comment: I want to read and use the data inside through js.

Comment: There's no `//` in the link you've given. Also note that a much bigger problem is that it's not valid JSON due to being wrapped in `()` and having a trailing `;`

Comment: Yes taht's what i meant sorry, how can i "remove" that ();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your API is not returning proper JSON. It returns something like `({proper JSON here})`. The `(` and `)` are not valid on JSON, so you need to trim them first and then parse the JSON.

**EDIT**:
I'm going to assume that you are using fetch, so in order to properly trim this you can do something like this:

```js
    fetch(/*your fetch params here*/)
    .then(x => x.text()) // convert the response to text
    .then(x => x.replace(/^\((.*)\);$/,'$1')) // remove the offending chars and keep the rest
    .then(JSON.parse) // parse the sanitized output
```

An example that you can just open your chrome console and run right now is this:

```js
fetch("http://www.etnassoft.com/api/v1/get/?id=589", {
    "credentials": "include",
    "headers": {
      "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3",
      "accept-language": "en-GB,en;q=0.9,es-ES;q=0.8,es;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6",
      "cache-control": "no-cache",
      "pragma": "no-cache",
      "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1"
    },
    "referrerPolicy": "no-referrer-when-downgrade",
    "body": null,
    "method": "GET",
    "mode": "cors"
  }).then(x => x.text())
  .then(x => x.replace(/^\((.*)\);$/, '$1'))
  .then(JSON.parse)
```

Comment: Yes that's what i want to know how to trim it.

Comment: I can edit my answer to show you how, but first I need to know how are you fetching that data. Are you using native fetch? Or some other library? Axios? Request.js?